# Starting service from another app with intent-filter

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service

Until a month ago I was successfully starting the service from another app of mine using `intent-filter`.

App A:

```
 <service
            android:name="com.example.app.MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.test.START" />
            </intent-filter>
</service>
```

App B:

```
public static Intent createExplicitIntent(Context context, Intent intent) {
    List<ResolveInfo> queryIntentServices = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(intent, 0);
    System.out.println(queryIntentServices.size());

    if (queryIntentServices.size() != 1) {
        return null;
    }

    ResolveInfo resolveInfo = queryIntentServices.get(0);
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(resolveInfo.serviceInfo.packageName, resolveInfo.serviceInfo.name);
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(intent);
    intent2.setComponent(componentName);
    return intent2;
}
```

And then finally:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("com.test.START");
 createExplicitIntent(context, intent);
```

But for some reason it stopped working. Not sure what I've changed that broke this approach.

Comment: What do you have in your `<queries>` element in your manifest in App B?

Comment: Nothing at all. I removed it. @CommonsWare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `<queries>` element in App B if you want your code to work on Android 11 and higher, as you need to [declare your package visibility needs](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring).

In your case, something like this might work:

```xml
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="com.test.START" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
```

Comment: Can I declare a partial package name? Like all apps that start with package name: "com.developername"

Comment: @DeborahAnn: If you mean using `<package>`, it does not look like that is an option based on the docs, though I have not tried it personally.

Comment: otherwise I should simply use QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES.

Comment: @DeborahAnn: You are unlikely to be allowed to ship your app on the Play Store with that permission.